# Getting a map from PageParameters in Wicket 1.5

Tags: wicket, openid4java

I'm trying to migrate an application using OpenId4Java to Wicket 1.5. Using the [migration notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html) I've gotten everything to work.

Except one thing: Before Wicket 1.5 PageParameters was a map which was perfect since OpenId4Java's [ParameterList](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/openid4java/message/ParameterList.html) took an map as an argument.

However in Wicket 1.5, I can't figure out how to get an map out of the PageParameters. 
Going trough the PageParameters NamedPairs and making a map of of that is not to hard. But creating an class (the creation of a ParameterLists are in several places) does not feel as a good solution.

What is the simpler solution to this?

```
ParameterList response = new ParameterList( pageParameters);
```

-- EDIT --
Code that solved the problem for me.

```
public static ParameterList toParameterList(PageParameters p){
    HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(NamedPair pair: p.getAllNamed()){
        h.put(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
    }
    return new ParameterList(h);
}

public static ParameterList toParameterList(IRequestParameters rP) {
    HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(String name : rP.getParameterNames()){
        h.put(name, rP.getParameterValue(name).toString());
    }
    return new ParameterList(h);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Upgrade-1-5-PageParameters-toRequestParameters-tp3871781p3873818.html for the same issue.

> The closest is org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters.getAllNamed() You can write a helper function to convert it to Map

Comment: This solved the problem. I put the code up here if anyone else needs it